# Some problems assigning roles with my Discord bot

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I had some issues with my bot assigning roles to a user who writes in a specific channel, but I can't figure out what the problem is. Here is my code:

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
  const menssage = message.content.toLocaleLowerCase();
  // First i want to limit my channel
  if (message.channel.id === '835461110349824021') {
    // Now if my user writes on this channel
    if (menssage) {
      // My bot will give him a role automatically
      message.author.roles.add('868240684346376262');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Do you receive any error? _I can't figure out what the problem is_  and _I had some issues_ is not the best way to get help. Try to read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first.

Comment: Please describe your problem. What are "some issues"? What did you expect to happen? What is actually happening? Did you get any error messages?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of fixes you have to make to your code.

First, is how you assign a role to a user. There is a difference between a `User` and `GuildMember` in `discord.js`, which is that `GuildMember` is specific to every `guild` (or server), whereas `User` is the user itself without anything `guild` specific.

In your code, it seems like you add roles with this line:

```
message.author.roles.add('868240684346376262');
```

This is faulty because `author` is a `User`, not a `GuildMember`, and you cannot add roles to a `User`, only to a `GuildMember` since roles are guild-specific.

To fix this, you can simply swap out `author` with `member` to get a `GuildMember` instead of a `User`:

```
//gets the member (I replaced "author" with "member") instead of the user
message.member.roles.add('868240684346376262');
```

Second, from what it seems like, you don't need the `menssage` at all (nor the `if` statement associated with it). Unless if I'm mistaken, you only need to check if the `message` is from the specific `channel` that you intended, nothing more. You may have other intentions that you did not specify, such as checking if the user wrote a specific phrase, then feel free to keep it in your code.

Comment: Nice answer but the _"you cannot simply use the ID of a `Role`"_ part is not true. [`member.roles.add()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=add) accepts a [snowflake](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/RoleResolvable) too.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I didn't realize that was a thing you could do! I've modified the answer accordingly.